# multiple select filter in javasvript

Tags: javascript

i am using to multiple select filter, i am trying multi select and filter in my table, but i have an problem, if i select only one value data are filter and show in my table but when i select multiple values data are not filter and show.

```js
function filterText() {
  var rex = new RegExp($('#filterText').val());
  alert(rex);
  if (rex == "/all/") {
    clearFilter()
  } else {

    $('.content').hide();
    $('.content').filter(function() {
      return rex.test($(this).text());
    }).show();
  }
}

function clearFilter() {
  $('.filterText').val('');
  $('.content').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='filterText' multiple="multiple" onchange='filterText()' name="filterText[]">
  <option disabled selected>Select</option>
  <option value='1'>Lower Case</option>
  <option value='2'>Upper Case</option>
  <option value='all'>All</option>
</select>

<table>
  <tr class="content">
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>Lower Case</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="content">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Larry</td>
    <td>the Bird</td>
    <td>Upper Case</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="content">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>Lower Case</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="content">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Jacob</td>
    <td>Thornton</td>
    <td>Upper Case</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I just want if i select Lowercase(value=1) and Uppercase(value=2) show both table.

Thanks.

Comment: (1) You cannot have `tr` elements outside of a `table` element. (2) You have an unclosed quote in the `onchange` attribute.

Comment: Sorry, i am new in javascript.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you select multiple entries? Should for a given row all of them be true at the same time, or just one of them?

Comment: Yes, i want which are selected only those are show others are hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fixed code.

`$('#filterText').val()` returns an array `.join('|')` makes the regex search either of the text available

```js
function filterText() {
  var rex = new RegExp($('#filterText').val().join('|'));
  alert(rex);
  if (rex == "/all/") {
    clearFilter()
  } else {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.content').filter(function() {
      return rex.test($(this).text());
    }).show();
  }
}

function clearFilter() {
  $('.filterText').val('');
  $('.content').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='filterText' multiple="multiple" onchange='filterText()' name="filterText[]">
  <option disabled selected>Select</option>
  <option value='Lower Case'>Lower Case</option>
  <option value='Upper Case'>Upper Case</option>
  <option value='all'>All</option>
</select>

<table>
  <tr class="content">
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>Lower Case</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="content">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Larry</td>
    <td>the Bird</td>
    <td>Upper Case</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="content">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>Lower Case</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="content">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Jacob</td>
    <td>Thornton</td>
    <td>Upper Case</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```